# Problems with link and button in ng2-handsontable for Angular2

Tags: angular, handsontable

This is my first Angular2 project and I use ng2-handsontable for grid.
And I have problem with ng2.handsontable.
Links and buttons are not working for me.

Grid settings:

```js
userItems: UserItem[]=[];
private colHeaders: Array<string> = ['View'];
private columns: Array<any> = [        
    {
      data: 'viewDetails',
      renderer: 'html',
      readOnly: true
    }
  ];

//After getting users populated, results are mapped 
mapUsers(users: UserItem[]): void {
    this.userItems = users;
        for (var userItem of this.userItems) {               
            userItem.viewDetails= '<a href='/admin/users/1'>Details</a>';
        }
}
```

Problem with link:

If I put href='/admin/users/1' in  tag, correct page will open. But whole angular application is loaded again.

```js
userItem.viewDetails= '<a href='/admin/users/1'>Details</a>';
```

Because of that I want to use routerlink.

When I create link like this routerlink='/admin/users/1' link is not called.

```js
userItem.viewDetails = '<a routerlink='/admin/users/1'> Details</a>';
```

Adding href=’#’ to this version, also does not help.

I also try: href="javascript:return auctions('1')" where auction is call to angular2 method, but that does not work.

```js
userItem.viewDetails= '<a href="javascript:return details('1')">Details</a>';
```

Problem with buttons in this grid is that on click angular action is not called.

```js
userItem.viewDetails= '<button (click)="details(1)">Details</button>';
```

Looking forward to suggestions :)

Comment: I give up from ng2-handsontable. I just create my own grid template which is working, just normal table with links and buttons without sorting implemented. Pity that there is still no good free grid for angular 2 which support angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this - angular-2-data-table-demo